# How to add 4 css or 4 different background color to the datatable rows using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am working with the dataTable, I am passing data to the table dynamically and I want to change the background color of rows for the first 4 rows and repeat those colors for the next set of 4 rows respectively and so on.

I tried using :nth-child css selector but i can select rows odd/even or specifying the row number i want to make like this below

```js
$("tr:nth-child(1)").css("background-color", "orange");
$("tr:nth-child(2)").css("background-color", "green");
$("tr:nth-child(3)").css("background-color", "blue");
$("tr:nth-child(4)").css("background-color", "yellow");
$("tr:nth-child(5)").css("background-color", "orange");
$("tr:nth-child(6)").css("background-color", "green");
$("tr:nth-child(7)").css("background-color", "blue");
$("tr:nth-child(8)").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

Comment: What have you tried and need help with? I'd suggest researching the [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) CSS selector

Comment: I tried using :nth-child css selector but i can select rows odd/even or specifying the row number
i want to make like this below
$("tr:nth-child(1)").css("background-color", "orange");
$("tr:nth-child(2)").css("background-color", "green");
$("tr:nth-child(3)").css("background-color", "blue");
$("tr:nth-child(4)").css("background-color", "yellow");
$("tr:nth-child(5)").css("background-color", "orange");
$("tr:nth-child(6)").css("background-color", "green");
$("tr:nth-child(7)").css("background-color", "blue");
$("tr:nth-child(8)").css("background-color", "yellow");

Comment: Thank you for adding the code, but note you should edit it in to the question as code in comments is unreadable. I've done it for you in this case. I've also added an answer for you below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already using the right selector, `:nth-child`, but you need to use functional notation to calculate the colour based on the current row index, `n`:

```js
$("tr:nth-child(4n+1)").css("background-color", "orange");
$("tr:nth-child(4n+2)").css("background-color", "green");
$("tr:nth-child(4n+3)").css("background-color", "blue");
$("tr:nth-child(4n+4)").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

```css
table { width: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>7</td></tr>
  <tr><td>8</td></tr>
</table>
```

That being said, you should not be using Javascript to do this. Use CSS directly:

```css
table { width: 100%; }

tr:nth-child(4n+1) { background-color: orange; }
tr:nth-child(4n+2) { background-color: green; }
tr:nth-child(4n+3) { background-color: blue; }
tr:nth-child(4n+4) { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>7</td></tr>
  <tr><td>8</td></tr>
</table>
```